# Check if binary data file type if PDF or not?

Tags: node.js, file-type

I have a PDF file or any other file. When I read that file content in Node.js, it gives me binary data. How can I determine if a binary data file type is PDF or not in Node.js?

Comment: What did you try? Show us some code.

Comment: You can try [`file-type` npm module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type). It supports PDF detection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PDF parsing library such as pdf-parse to check if a file, buffer etc. is a valid PDF:

```
const rp = require("request-promise-native");
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');

const testUrl1 = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
const testUrl2 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#/media/File:Cat_poster_1.jpg";

function getPDF(url) {
    return rp({ uri: url, encoding: null});
}

function isPDF(buffer) {
    return pdf(buffer).then(function(data) {
        return { isPDF: true, info: data.info };
    }, (err) => {
        return { isPDF: false, info: null };
    });
}

async function testPDFCheck(url) {

    let pdfBuffer = await getPDF(url);
    let result = await isPDF(pdfBuffer);
    console.log(`Is PDF result: (${url}): `, result);
}

testPDFCheck(testUrl1);
testPDFCheck(testUrl2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this https://github.com/MaraniMatias/isPDF

```
const fs = require("fs");
const isPDF = require("is-pdf-valid");

const file = fs.readFileSync("./test.pdf")
console.log(isPDF(file));
```

Comment: Good simple approach :-) I've used `buf.slice(0, 5).toString() === '%PDF-' && buf.slice(-5).toString() === '%%EOF'`

Comment: doesnt work for bad files with malicious code in between header and end of file